# Property procedure definitions inconsistent - Get and Set VBA

Tags: vba

Error:

[image]

Code:

```
Private pColumnLabels() As MSForms.Label

Public Property Get Column(Index As Integer) As MSForms.Label
    'some irrelevant code here
    Set Column = pColumnLabels(Index)
End Property

Public Property Set Column(lbl As MSForms.Label, Index As Integer) <--- errornous line
    Set pColumnLabels(Index) = lbl
End Property
```

Basically I'm creating something similar to ListBox control (but with the ability to adjust specific cells to my liking, e.g. background color, font etc) and so each of my rows has multiple columns. I create labels elsewhere and then I want to assign these labels to the array that holds it for each row.

Given index, I want to return (`Get`) the label for that specific column, such that for example `row.Column(0).caption` would return caption for the given column.

Provided label and index will `Set` the label to that specific row, such that: `Set row.Column(0) = someLabel`. I can see why the Set is wrong, ie. I should be doing something like `Set row.Column = {someLabel, 0}`, but that's not possible in VBA.

Any suggestion how to make this neat? I know I can create a function that will be passing the parameters, ie something like:

```
Public Function passParams(lbl as MSForms.Label, Index as Integer)
    Set pColumnLabels(Index) = lbl
End Function
```

But then I don't get the nice functionality of being able to do the examples I provided above, that is, instead of:

```
row.Column(0).caption         'get
Set row.Column(0) = someLabel 'set
```

I would have to do

```
row.Column(0).caption             'get
Call row.passParams(someLabel, 0) 'set
```

Comment: What is pColumnLabels?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav `Private pColumnLabels() As MSForms.Label`

Comment: Is this defined to hold the labels, i.e. does an index of x exist in this array? as it's defined empty  check if index<=ubound(pcolumnlabels)

Comment: I do the checks in `'some irrelevant code here` section to ensure proper array size.

Comment: and you redim it then?  so it has to have GET called before SET will work I think

Comment: I initialise the array with the class initialisation to give it 1 label space (ie. `ReDim pColumnLabels(0)` as it will always hold at least 1 column. Afterwards every time I GET I make sure that it is not out of bounds, and in case of SET I ReDim Preserve to extend the columns if needed. The problem is the Set with those 2 arguments is throwing the error I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set to parameter needs to be last, this I got working

```
Option Explicit

Private pColumnLabels() As MSForms.Label

Public Property Get columnx(i As Integer) As MSForms.Label
    Set columnx = pColumnLabels(i)
End Property

Public Property Set columnx(i As Integer, lbl As MSForms.Label)
    Set pColumnLabels(i) = lbl
End Property
```